# Git Distribution of Unreal Engine game

Tags: git, unreal-engine4

I am tying to distribute my unreal engine game to friends via git. I have a git repository for the game hosted on my server at my house. The packaged game works fine. However, when I push to the git repository and pull that version it errors with:

> Failed to open descriptor file
> ../../../cod_improved/cod_improved.uproject

cod_improved being the name of the project.
There is no file in the original build of cod_improved.uproject.
I am thinking that there is a file somewhere in the project that is not getting transferred or not getting transferred correctly. 
Does anyone know what is happening?

The .pak file in the original is 4,608,692 kB where the cloned one is 414,388 kB which appears to be the problem. How can I push that file in its entirety?

Comment: `..` refers to a _parent_ directory, so these files may be outside of where you started the git repository and linked in somehow

Comment: Copying the contents of WindowsNoEditor which is the parent of the game's files to another location works just fine. The .pak file is the issue as copying it from the original to the clone makes the game work.

Comment: Perhaps, you have some file in .gitignore so it doesn't go into your repo?